# Angular test failure when I make http call

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

This is my dashboard.component.ts file:

```
import { Post } from "./../models/post";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-dashboard",
  templateUrl: "./dashboard.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./dashboard.component.css"]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  title: string = "Hello World!";
  posts: Post[] = [];

  addNumber(a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

This is my dashboard.component.spec.ts file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";

import { DashboardComponent } from "./dashboard.component";

describe("DashboardComponent", () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DashboardComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should add two numbers", () => {
    expect(component.addNumber(1, 1)).toBe(2);
  });

  it("title should contain the word Hello", () => {
    expect(component.title).toContain("Hello");
  });
});
```

Everything is ok, both of the tests are successes.
But when I want to adding http call with my service like this:

dashboard.component.ts file after adding the http call:

```
import { Post } from "./../models/post";
import { PostService } from "./../services/posts-api.service";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-dashboard",
  templateUrl: "./dashboard.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./dashboard.component.css"]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private postService: PostService) {}

  title: string = "Hello World!";
  posts: Post[] = [];

  addNumber(a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.posts = posts;
    });
  }
}
```

The http call is success but now the test is failed, why? the spec file with no change:

NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yout need to add `HttpClientTestingModule` to your spec file because you inject the PostService using HttpCient itself:

```
import {HttpClientTestingModule} from "@angular/common/http/testing";

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DashboardComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: why? but I dont want to test the service at all.

Comment: As PostService is part of the constructor of your component, you need to resolve it to make your component works correctly. But to make your PostService works correctly too, you need to care about its own constructor too, where HttpClient is included. That's why at the end, you test needs to include HttpClientTestingModule.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much!